# Is there a way to avoid crashes in app in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

just wanted to know is there a way to avoid crashes in Xamarin applications specifically in android.

Currently I am using below codes to catch issues or bugs-

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser;
```

But as per documentation these are just to catch and trace the issue,but still the app will crash.

so please provide a solution for crashes,currently i have an big application where i am able track issues,but the problem is i cant release a new version at the moment due to some issues,but in future i want to write codes where any kind of issue occurs ,at least the application should not crash..

Comment: Basically, no.  You need to handle the underlying condition(s) that are causing the crash to avoid them.  Use something like appcenter.ms to get automated crash reporting data that you can use to track down and fix the causes of the crash.

Comment: HI Jason,Thanks for comment,but like i mentioned i am able to track exceptions and crashes issues in my server...but the problem is -app can be crash due any reason,so just want to avoid this crash(just app should not exit)

Comment: No, you can't avoid crashes in app at run time.